# Echar, arrojar, tirar, lanzar... for throwing oneself in a river

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, solicitud-de-término, sinónimos, puerto-rico

I am writing a poem where the persona wants to throw herself into the river. The persona is Puertoriqueña. I had typed "Voy a echarme" but I am wondering if 'arrojarme', 'tirarme', or even 'lanzarme' would be better.

This particular river is in a gorge, and would be quite a dive or fall. Would the diference in word choice depend on the degree of violence felt in the act?

Comment: Uhms, interesting. What do you want to mean with "throw herself"? Just doing it for fun or because of some drama? Just to have some more context

Comment: @fedorqui - this expression, especially with the contextual information provided by OP, means *definitely not for fun*.  Yes, drama.

Comment: Wendy, I think you're going to want to be careful to spell her nationality like this in your poem: *puertorriqueña*. // Google can be your friend for usage questions. I googled *suicidio aventarse al río* and found https://www.elsoldecordoba.com.mx/policia/en-aparente-suicidio-muere-joven-mujer-al-aventarse-de-un-puente. That would be a first step. Then you'd want to look more closely, at Puerto Rican newspapers, because of regional variation. I was just guessing with *aventarse* but if I had guessed something else I probably would have still gotten an article with *aventarse* somewhere in it.

Comment: For me all options are the same. If it is a poem then it should rhyme then your choice will depend on the other sentences around.

Answer (score 1):

All of them sounds good to me, but my least favorite are "tirarme and echarme", by the intensity of the act (a gorge is kind of a big jump) y would use lanzarme.

Now, about connotations :

from worst to the best

> **Tirarme** has  definitely the worst connotation (almost like giving up) as tirar almost means to throw away.
>
> **Arrojarme** has a mid level connotation, not bad or good, but is not neutral either, as when you "arrojas" mostly is to the unknown and unexpected
>   example: "ser arrojado" is an expression of someone who fears nothing but also expects the worst.
>
> **Echarme** is the true neutral connotation, and so neutral it actually depicts laziness as when someone "se echa" is almost like lying down.
>
> On the other hand **Lanzarme** has an adventurous connotation, like going to the adventure and the unknown but like a lance, sharp, fast, brave and directed.
>   in contrast to "ser arrojado, "ser lanzado" is someone who goes for the victory

Remember that poetry is more about the embodiment of the feelings that the one of the actions, and if you want to tell that someone is jumping on a cliff you don't need to put it exactly into words...

we can change "echarme" or "tirarme" to "perderme"
we can change "lanzarme" to "atreverme" or "enfrentarme"

Comment: "Aventarse" has also a violent connotation. The word may imply an attempt of suicide. For example "aventarse a las vías del metro", "aventarse de un puente".

Comment: yes, I forgot about Aventar !!! , but while the connotation of aventar is aggressive it is not negative, that's a regionalism. it has a stronger feeling of the unknown and the wild as the word comes from "ventar" that means "with the wind". but even again. going to the unknown might provoke a negative feeling as we know that the unknown is the darkness